# How to add to date in DATE column days that exceed to the next month?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to add 7 days to each DATE value. when i add 7 days to the date "2015-11-19" its working and i the new value is "2015-11-26" but when i add it to the "2015-11-26" the date value become "0000-00-00"
this is my query:

```
UPDATE events SET events.event_date = DATE(events.event_date + 7)
```

just for note when i use the next query:

```
UPDATE events SET events.event_date = DATE(events.event_date , interval 7 day)
```

i get those errors:

```
Unrecognized keyword. (near "interval" at position 62)
Unexpected token. (near "7" at position 71)
Unexpected token. (near ")" at position 72)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use  `DATE_ADD(Date,INTERVAL 45 DAY)`

like this

```
UPDATE events SET events.event_date =DATE_ADD(events.event_date,INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `DATE_ADD` function from mysql.

The Link would be [DATE_ADD()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

So the Query becomes

`UPDATE events SET events.event_date = DATE_ADD(events.event_date , interval 7 day)`

Answer (score 1):

That second argument makes no sense in `DATE`. That function only takes a single argument. Perhaps what you wanted was `DATE_ADD` instead, which does take two arguments.

You can either do `DATE(events.event_date + INTERVAL 7 DAY)` or you can do `DATE_ADD(events.event_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY)`. Both are semantically identical.